# Text replaced in HTML document being wrap in multilevel of tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom, replace

I want to bold all text in range **`[\u4e00-\ua000]`**. Chrome replace it successfully, but some how it wrap my character inside multilevel tag.

Bellow is my code. The first snippet is my HTML and javascript. The second is what Chrome had generate.

**Note:** The code snippet say there is error in the script but real browser run it happily.

## Code:

```js
<script>
    function walkText(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            node.parentNode.innerHTML = node.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(/[\u4e00-\ua000]/g,
                function(a) {
                    return '<b class="myChineseChar">' + a + '</b>';
                }
            );
            return;
        }
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != "SCRIPT") {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                walkText(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    walkText(document.body);


    function test(a) {
        alert(a.innerHTML);
    }


    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myChineseChar");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].addEventListener("wheel", test);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<html><body><div>We call it 一天一夜。<br/>Something like that</div></body></html>
```

## Result

Here is result on Chrome browser. Don't know why it make so many wrap of my characters:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div>We call it 
  <b class="myChineseChar">
   <b class="myChineseChar">
    <b class="myChineseChar">
     <b class="myChineseChar">
      <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
     </b>
    </b>
   </b>
  </b>
  <b class="myChineseChar">
   <b class="myChineseChar">
    <b class="myChineseChar">
     <b class="myChineseChar">
      <b class="myChineseChar">天</b>
     </b>
    </b>
   </b>
  </b>
  <b class="myChineseChar">
   <b class="myChineseChar">
    <b class="myChineseChar">
     <b class="myChineseChar">
      <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
     </b>
    </b>
   </b>
  </b>
  <b class="myChineseChar">
   <b class="myChineseChar">
    <b class="myChineseChar">
     <b class="myChineseChar">
      <b class="myChineseChar">夜</b>
     </b>
    </b>
   </b>
  </b>
  <br>Something like that
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

## Desired result:

```html
<html>
 <body>
 <div>We call it 
  <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
  <b class="myChineseChar">天</b>
  <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
  <b class="myChineseChar">夜</b>。
  <br>Something like that
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Question: Where is error in my code and how I solve it to get desired result?

**Note:** The code in my answer bellow can partially solve the problem, but not output the same desired output. I'm still looking for better answer.

**Note:** I need replace all text in my document, no matter it lay in what tag, but:

- It must only replace inside text nodes, and not text in other places, ie in javascript, for example.

Comment: In `walkText` it looks like you want to operate on `node`, then why are you modifying the `innerHTML` of `node.parentNode`? Shouldn't it be `node.innerHTML`?

Comment: @bloopletech I tried that, but `node` is text node, so `node.innerHTML` will output as plain text, not as HTML

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the code a bit :)
Now it works.
The problem was with going through parent element of each child element and replacing a character. You ended up with n replacements

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='ssss'>We call it 一 天 一 夜
    <br>Something like that
  </div>
  <script>
    function walkText(node) {
      node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/[\u4e00-\ua000]/g,
        function(a) {
          return '<b class="myChineseChar">' + a + '</b>';
        }
      );
      return;
    }

    walkText(document.body);


    function test(a) {
      alert(a.innerHTML);
    }


    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myChineseChar");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].addEventListener("wheel", test);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: characters that need to be replace are not neccessery lay inside a `DIV`. My code is only a sample. I need to replace ***all text*** in whole document.

Comment: It'll replace all Chinese Chars in the body element

Answer (score 0):

This code bellow can partially solve the problem:

## Code:

```js
< script >
function walkText(node) {
 if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != "SCRIPT") {
 for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
  if (node.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3 && /[\u4e00-\ua000]/.test(node.childNodes[i].data)) {
  var elmnt = document.createElement("span");
  elmnt.innerHTML = node.childNodes[i].data.replace(/[\u4e00-\ua000]/g,
   function(a) {
   return '<b class="myChineseChar">' + a + "</b>";
   }
  );
  node.replaceChild(elmnt, node.childNodes[i]);
  } else walkText(node.childNodes[i]);
 }
 }
 return 0;
}
walkText(document.body);


function test(a) {
alert(a.innerHTML);
}


var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myChineseChar");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].addEventListener("wheel", test);
} < /script>
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    We call it 一天一夜。
    <br/> Something like that
    <div>
      We call it 一天一夜。
      <p>
        We call it 一天一夜。
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The result it output will not being multilevel wrap as in my question, but it will place all text inside **`SPAN`** tag, which is acceptable, but not perfect:

## Result:

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <span>
         We call it 
         <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
         <b class="myChineseChar">天</b>
         <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
         <b class="myChineseChar">夜</b>。
         </span>
         <br/>
         Something like that
         <div>
            <span>
            We call it 
            <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
            <b class="myChineseChar">天</b>
            <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
            <b class="myChineseChar">夜</b>。
            </span>
            <p>
               <span>
               We call it 
               <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
               <b class="myChineseChar">天</b>
               <b class="myChineseChar">一</b>
               <b class="myChineseChar">夜</b>。
               </span>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```